# How read data in PSW (program status word) in IBM mainframe

Tags: operating-system, cobol, mainframe

The message is:
[image]

I know 0C7 is a data error, but how can i read PSW abend code?

Answer (score 2):

The PSW is not and does not contain an abend-code, it shows the processor state at the time of the abend.

The PSW in your example has 8 bytes, so it's in ESA/390 format (in 64-bit-mode the PSW is 16 bytes), so I' focus on that case.

Usually the only thing that matters when investigating a 0C7 abend is the last 31 bits that contain the NSI - the next sequential instruction - pointing to the machine-statement after the statement causing the exception. In your case would be the address `60009260`. You'd have to investigate the statement before that address to see what data it is using and then investigate why it is not in the correct format.

On the other hand the shown PSW starts with `FF` - which should never be the case (see below), so the value shown is probably corrupted and the NSI-value should also be treated with a certain amount of suspicion.

To answer the question as stated here's the complete PSW-layout (all offsets and lengths are for bits):

- offset 0, length 1: always `0` (`1`in your example!!!)
- offset 1, length 1: Program Event Recording flag
- offset 2, length 3: always `000`
- offset 5, length 1: dynamic address translation flag
- offset 6, length 1: IO-interruptions flag
- offset 7, length 1: external-interruptions flag
- offset 8, length 4: PSW-Key (compared with storage-key for storage protection)
- offset 12, length 1: always `1`
- offset 13, length 1: machine-check-interruptions flag
- offset 14, length 1: wait-state flag
- offset 15, length 1: problem-state flag
- offset 16, length 2: address-space control
- offset 18, length 2: condition code (set e.g. by compare-instructions)
- offset 20, length 4: program mask (set e.g. by arithmetic instructions on overflow)
- offset 24, length 1: IBM-reserved
- offset 25, length 6: always `000000`
- offset 31, length 1: extended-addressing-mode flag (`1` means 64-bit-addressing)
- offset 32, length 1: basic.addressing-mode flag (`1` means 31-bit-addressing as opposed to 24-bit)
- offset 33, length 31: next sequential instruction

Further details on the meaning of the various flags as well as the layout of the 64-bit PSW can be found in the "Control"-chapter of the "z/Architecture Principles of Operation" manual.